# Experiencing error while doing regex installation using pip on python3

Tags: python, regex, pip

I'm trying to use the modern regex package to take advantage of unicode characters of languages other than English like Russian etc.

I've updated my pip and all other related modules using the command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

While I try to run `pip install regex`, it results in the following error which I'm unable to debug or breakdown to carry out a google search.

```
/Users/*****/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/qs/47tksnkj3s96ycg8ns88k6p4z4hz_b/T/pip-install-ssyqy0zi/regex/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/qs/47tksnkj3s96ycg8ns88k6p4z4hz_b/T/pip-install-ssyqy0zi/regex/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/qs/47tksnkj3s96ycg8ns88k6p4z4hz_b/T/pip-record-lnaoq70s/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/var/folders/qs/47tksnkj3s96ycg8ns88k6p4z4hz_b/T/pip-install-ssyqy0zi/regex/
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/regex
    copying regex_3/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/regex
    copying regex_3/regex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/regex
    copying regex_3/_regex_core.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/regex
    copying regex_3/test_regex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/regex
    running build_ext
    building 'regex._regex' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/regex_3
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Users/ayadav/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/include/python3.7m -c regex_3/_regex.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/regex_3/_regex.o
    xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/ayadav/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/qs/47tksnkj3s96ycg8ns88k6p4z4hz_b/T/pip-install-ssyqy0zi/regex/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/qs/47tksnkj3s96ycg8ns88k6p4z4hz_b/T/pip-install-ssyqy0zi/regex/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/qs/47tksnkj3s96ycg8ns88k6p4z4hz_b/T/pip-record-lnaoq70s/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+xcrun%3A+error%3A+invalid+active+developer+path+missing+xcrun

Comment: Thanks @phd, your suggestion did solve the problem.